# failed to create a child event loop/failed to open a new selector/Too many open files

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, cassandra-driver

I am getting errors like "failed to create a child event loop/failed to open a new selector/Too many open files" when **there are 30 or more concurrent requests**...How to solve the above errors? Am I doing anything wrong? I am using Spring boot and Java cassandra driver. **Below is the connection file**:

```
public class Connection {

public static Session getConnection() {

    final Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(ConnectionBean.getCASSANDRA_DB_IP())
            .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE))
            .withCredentials(ConnectionBean.getCASSANDRA_USER(), ConnectionBean.getCASSANDRA_PASSWORD())
            .withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
            .build();
    final Session session = cluster.connect(ConnectionBean.getCASSANDRA_DB_NAME());
    return session;
}
```

}

**Below is the ConnectionBean file which I used in Connection file:**

```
public  class ConnectionBean {

public static   String CASSANDRA_DB_IP;
public static String CASSANDRA_DB_NAME;
public static  String CASSANDRA_USER;
public static String CASSANDRA_PASSWORD;

public ConnectionBean() {

}
public ConnectionBean(String CASSANDRA_DB_IP,String CASSANDRA_DB_NAME,String CASSANDRA_USER,String CASSANDRA_PASSWORD) {
this.CASSANDRA_DB_IP=CASSANDRA_DB_IP;
this.CASSANDRA_DB_NAME=CASSANDRA_DB_NAME;
this.CASSANDRA_USER=CASSANDRA_USER;
this.CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=CASSANDRA_PASSWORD;
}

public static String getCASSANDRA_DB_IP() {
    return CASSANDRA_DB_IP;
}
public static void setCASSANDRA_DB_IP(String cASSANDRA_DB_IP) {
    CASSANDRA_DB_IP = cASSANDRA_DB_IP;
}
public static String getCASSANDRA_DB_NAME() {
    return CASSANDRA_DB_NAME;
}
public static void setCASSANDRA_DB_NAME(String cASSANDRA_DB_NAME) {
    CASSANDRA_DB_NAME = cASSANDRA_DB_NAME;
}
public static String getCASSANDRA_USER() {
    return CASSANDRA_USER;
}
public static void setCASSANDRA_USER(String cASSANDRA_USER) {
    CASSANDRA_USER = cASSANDRA_USER;
}
public static String getCASSANDRA_PASSWORD() {
    return CASSANDRA_PASSWORD;
}
public static void setCASSANDRA_PASSWORD(String cASSANDRA_PASSWORD) {
    CASSANDRA_PASSWORD = cASSANDRA_PASSWORD;
}
```

}

**Below is the class from where ConnectionBean variables are initialized :**

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
private static final String LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL = "/login";
private static final String LOGIN_FAILURE_URL = "/login?error";
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "/login";

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
private String usersQuery;

@Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
private String rolesQuery;

@Value("${CASSANDRA_DB_IP}")
public String CASSANDRA_DB_IP;

@Value("${CASSANDRA_DB_NAME}")
public String CASSANDRA_DB_NAME;

@Value("${CASSANDRA_USER}")
public String CASSANDRA_USER;

@Value("${CASSANDRA_PASSWORD}")
public String CASSANDRA_PASSWORD;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    ConnectionBean cb = new ConnectionBean(CASSANDRA_DB_IP, CASSANDRA_DB_NAME, CASSANDRA_USER, CASSANDRA_PASSWORD);

    auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
            .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // Not using Spring CSRF here to be able to use plain HTML for the login page

    http.csrf().disable()

            // Register our CustomRequestCache, that saves unauthorized access attempts, so
            // the user is redirected after login.
            .requestCache().requestCache(new CustomRequestCache())

            // Restrict access to our application.
            .and().authorizeRequests()

            // Allow all flow internal requests.
            .requestMatchers(SecurityUtils::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll()

            // Allow all requests by logged in users.
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            // Configure the login page.
            .and().formLogin().loginPage(LOGIN_URL).permitAll().loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL)
            .failureUrl(LOGIN_FAILURE_URL)

            // Register the success handler that redirects users to the page they last tried
            // to access
            .successHandler(new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler())

            // Configure logout
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl(LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL);
}

/**
 * Allows access to static resources, bypassing Spring security.
 */
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(
            // Vaadin Flow static resources
            "/VAADIN/**",

            // the standard favicon URI
            "/favicon.ico",

            // web application manifest
            "/manifest.json", "/sw.js", "/offline-page.html",

            // icons and images
            "/icons/**", "/images/**",

            // (development mode) static resources
            "/frontend/**",

            // (development mode) webjars
            "/webjars/**",

            // (development mode) H2 debugging console
            "/h2-console/**",

            // (production mode) static resources
            "/frontend-es5/**", "/frontend-es6/**");
}
```

}

**And finally, below is the class through which I am querying cassandra data:**

```
public class getData {
Session session;

public getData(){
    session = Connection.getConnection();
    getDataTable();
}

private void getDataTable() {
    try {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM tableName";
        ResultSet rs = session.execute(query);
        for (Row row : rs) {
            /*Do some stuff here using row*/
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No..here concern is Java Cassandra driver is giving above error if there are 30 concurrent user request, it's working fine with 15 concurrent users

Comment: My guess is that your database has a connection limit. Which you'd need to increase. Or work with a queue. Where you just have e.g. 10 workers.

Comment: May I know form where to check database connection limit? I also tried java-cassandra driver PoolingOptions with MaxQueueSize = 4096 and MaxRequestsPerConnection = 32768....Thanks!!!

Comment: Probably in the database itself... I don't know cassandra, but you'll probably find it on google when searching something like: "Cassandra set connection limit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `getConnection()` is being invoked for every request,  you are creating a new `Cluster` instance each time.

This is discouraged because one connection is created between your client and a C* node for each `Cluster` instance, and for each `Session` a connection pool of at least one connection is created for each C* node.

If you are not closing your `Cluster` instances after a request completes, these connections will remain open.  After a number of requests, you'll have so many connections open that you will run out of file descriptors in your OS.

To resolve this issue, create only one `Cluster` and `Session` instance and reuse it between requests.  This strategy is outlined in [4 simple rules when using the DataStax drivers for Cassandra](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/4-simple-rules-when-using-the-datastax-drivers-for-cassandra):

> 1. Use one Cluster instance per (physical) cluster (per application lifetime)
> 2. Use at most one Session per keyspace, or use a single Session and explicitely specify the keyspace in your queries